# Android Image on Image button not displayed

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

I facing the problem that, I cant add new image button to my  XML file.I added my icons to Drawable, but It cannot show in image button. XML shows an error ImageButton class not found. How can I solve this ?

I got the following error in xml

The following classes could not be found:
- ImageButton (Change to android.widget.ImageButton, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Here is my xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please upload your code

Comment: If you have used selector in xml, make sure its lower case `selector` instead of `Selector`. And make sure the image name are proper. Without upper case character or special character.

Comment: See my new edit , here is my xml

Comment: Did you try clean + build?

Comment: I already tried clean and build.. but it still not working with my images on drawable

Comment: Ok.. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5051881/1777090) answer if it helps.

Comment: i am not using selector. Just added image to drawable. so this answer not helpful :(

Comment: my problem is I cant show the images on the image button.It wrks when I am using the Images that are already in the drawable folder

Comment: Your question doesn't say the same problem you mentioned in your last comment...question says 'I added my icons to Drawable, but It cannot show in image button' your comment says 'It wrks when I am using the Images that are already in the drawable folder'. isn't it contradictory?

Comment: I mean I can show images on imagebutton by using images like ic_launcher(default image).But when I am adding a new one.It will not display

Comment: i got the error The following classes could not be found:
- ImageButton (Change to android.widget.ImageButton, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you try a simple button instead of image button. Here is a code i have on some of my buttons with image. 
`android:drawableTop="@drawable/three"` : this is basically the image
`android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"` : this is a style for the button. No need to use it. Or the other layout features i have.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/three"
        android:onClick="goToSettings"
        android:text="Settings" />
```

Comment: I got the error   The following classes could not be found:
- ImageButton (Change to android.widget.ImageButton, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Comment: try to make a new button and add drawableTop with the link to the image. And see if that works.
This error you posted was produced from the code i linked?

Answer (score 2):

I was using the interface builder and for some reason, it added this

```
tools:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_100dp"
```

Change it to this to make it work and display image in image button

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_100dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My images were .ico and I had the same error message in the Graphical Layout tab in eclipse. I proved to transform the .ico images to .png images and then I deleted the .ico and I imported the .png to the project. 
It was succesful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
    android:src="@drawable/a" />

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
       android:src="@drawable/a" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: my problem is I cant show the images on the image button.It wrks when I am using the Images that are already in the drawable folder

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   plz try to remove it from xml

Answer (score 0):

I think this not big issue. Your is right nothing wrong with you posted. In my eclipse it works fine.

1. First check images properly put in drawable folder with small letter naming convention.  or  if you only have it in /res/drawable-xhdpi/ please check this also. May use this background instead of src.
2. if you not not getting R cannot resolve with putting image in xml, then first `Refresh` project, if is not work then `clean` whole project, if this is also not work `restart` eclipse.
3. if you restart eclipse, then it not work, may be your project library not properly located.

Answer (score 0):

Change `extend Activity` to `extend AppCompatActivity` in your Activity Class

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Button as ImageButton in java classes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).